# Como ponho barra de rolagem no card do materialize?

Tags: materialize

```
<div class="col s12 m4 l8">
  <div class="card-panel">
    <h4><center>Título da Reunião</center></h4>
    <div id="primary">
    <div id="log">
       <span class="long-content">&nbsp;</span>
    </div>
<div id="composer">
    <form name="form_message" id="form_message" method="post" action="set_message.ajax.php">
      <input name="nickname" type="hidden" id="nickname" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['nickname']; ?>">
     <div class="row">
     <div class="col s10">
     <input name="message" type="text" autofocus required class="textbox_message" id="message">
</div> 
<div class="col s2">
  <button class="btn-large red darken-3  waves-effect waves-light" id="btn_send" name="action">
      <i class="material-icons ">send</i>
  </button> 
</div>
```

Estou criando um chat, mas queria que o card ficasse fixo em vez de aumentar de tamanho toda vez que aparece uma msg.Como faço para colocar uma barra de rolagem?

Comment: Coloque o código que já desenvolveu se possível para obter maior ajuda no site.

Answer (score 0):

Limite a altura do card com a `classes de tamanho`, coloque a classe **small** para o card ter tamanho máximo de **300px**, a classe **medium** para o card ter tamanho máximo de **400px** ou a classe **large** para  o card ter tamanho máximo de **500px**;

```
<div class="card-panel small">    
    <h4><center>Título da Reunião</center></h4>
```

> Mais informações acesse [aqui](https://materializecss.com/cards.html).